# How can I replace HTML tags with &lt; or &gt;

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**View**

```
<%= auto_link(simple_format(strip_tags(@string))) %>
```

"strip_tags" erases whole content inside of the `<>`

How can I replace them with `&lt;` or `&gt;` instead?

Is there any function to do it?
I mean I want to escape **@string**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `h` helper function:

```
<%= auto_link(simple_format(h(@string))) %>
```

Comment: Here's the [docs for `h/html_escape`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape), for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Add following in `app/helpers/application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper

  def raw_strip(text)
    raw(text).gsub('<', '&lt;').gsub('>', '&gt;')
  end
end
```

Then, use `raw_strip(@string)` in your view.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do I need to include ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper?????

Comment: Not necessarily, I think. Helper are already included in views which include that module; so, it must work without that too. Added that for failsafe.

Answer (score 1):

just use the h() method, as the example below:

```
puts h("is a > 0 & a < 10?")
```

produces the following output:

```
is a &gt; 0 &amp; a &lt; 10?
```

Note: if you are doing it on a console, you'll have to do some extra steps:

```
require "erb"
include ERB::Util
```